# Using Jquery-fileupload plugin without the <form> tag?

Tags: asp.net, forms, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to integrate [Jquery File Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) in my aspx page (asp.net website). I followed the guide, including all required scripts and stylesheets, but in the [index.html](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/index.html#L76) it's used a `form` tag to initialize the plugin and with the tag are also specified `action` and `method` attributes. Since I'm using asp.net, I am not allowed to insert the `form` tag because asp.net wrap the whole website with another `form` tag and it doesn't allow to insert another `form` tag inside it.

How can I initialize the plugin in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually have to have a form to use jQuery file upload plugin. Because the plugin is using jQuery ajax under the hood. use the bellow code inside your page, keep in mind you have to code an API on the server side.

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = 'your server api or handler';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```

and your html as follows:

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        <span>Select files...</span>
        <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- The global progress bar -->
    <div id="progress" class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
    <div id="files" class="files"></div>
```